# How to target and assign specific child elements when the child elements only render on a onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I have two selectfield dropdowns that I made that are wrapped under a parent container.  They both have dropdowns that have the same classnames so I decided to use the ':nth-child' selector to target either the first or second child.

```
    .select-field {

       .dropdown-list {

          &:nth-child(1) {
            top: 342px;
          }

          &:nth-child(2) {
            top: 404px;
          }
       }
    }
```

However it's applying the ':nth-child(2)' style for both children.  I realized this might be the case because only one or the other dropdown list is rendered in the DOM when only one of the select field dropdowns is clicked.  So if I click on the first select field, the dropdown for the first select field is seen in the DOM but the dropdown for the second select field is not which is understandable.  So I think it only recognizes one child.

If first selectfield is clicked and vice versa:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="select-field">
  <div class="dropdown-list">
   <ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class="select-field">
 *other dropdown is not rendered*
 </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to apply these styles considering these dropdown list are dependent on an event?

Comment: You're defining the classes of the elements wrong. It should be `<div class="...">`. You don't need the extra "Name".

Comment: Oh sorry it's actually 'class' in the dom. I'm working in React so they call their classes 'className'.  I wrote the example manually.  Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: You are applying `:nth-child` to the `dropdown-list`, which according to your code _is_ the _only_ child to `.select-field`. If you want to select the second dropdown, maybe try `.select-field:nth-child(2) .dropdown-list`?

Comment: That's really SCSS, not CSS, and your HTML is invalid. But, like @somethinghere stated `:nth-child` applies to the Element that it's attached to, not the children of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @somethinghere pointed out you need to target the `select-field` with `:nth-child` selector:

```
.select-field {
  &:nth-child(1) .dropdown-list {
    top: 342px;
    border: 2px dashed black; 
  }
  
  &:nth-child(2) .dropdown-list {
    top: 404px;
    border: 2px dashed gold;
  }
}
```